# What styles are used by tabStyleName?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, stylesheet

The language reference says "Name of CSS style declaration that specifies styles for the tabs. The default value is undefined." But, what is the "type" of style that is being used? That is, what style properties can I put in that style definition.

For example, I wish to set the disabledColor of the text on the tab. I couldnt seem to do it. Worse, I haven't been able to find out what I can do!

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how do I go about doing that?

Comment: In the questions you've asked, find the one that answered your question and click the check mark. It's that simple. Also, it's covered in the FAQ under the topic "How do I ask questions here?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/TabNavigator.html), the `tabStyleName` style applies to the `Tab` class used - which is hidden and hence not available in online reference. You can look up the source - go to the installation folder of flex and find the correct version sdk, and browse down to the file `mx\controls\tabBarClasses\Tab.as` - you should be able to find the style properties accepted by that class in there.

> The Tab type selector defines values on the hidden `mx.controls.tabBarClasses.Tab` class.
>   The default values for the Tab type selector are defined in the defaults.css file.
>
> You can also define the styles in a class selector that you specify using the `tabStyleName` style property; for example:

```
<mx:Style>
TabNavigator {
   tabStyleName:myTabStyle;
}
 .myTabStyle {
   fillColors: #006699, #cccc66;
   upSkin: ClassReference("CustomSkinClass");
   overSkin: ClassReference("CustomSkinClass");
   downSkin: ClassReference("CustomSkinClass");
}
</mx:Style>
```

---

Write the css in the *style.css* file

```
.myTabStyle
{
    disabledColor: #B0B0B0;
}
```

Include the CSS file in to your `Application` file using:

```
<mx:Style source="style.css"/>
```

Now you can set it as:

```
<mx:TabNavigator tabStyleName="myTabStyle" other="attributes"/>
```

If you don't want a separate css file, you can inline the css using:

```
<mx:Style>
.myTabStyle
{
    disabledColor: #B0B0B0;
}
</mx:Style>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you have misunderstood my question. I would like to know what properties I can put in the style definition.

Comment: That Tab class extends mx.controls.Button, so just take a look at the documentation for Button (linked from eruciform's answer) and you will find the styles you can use.

Answer (score 0):

This is your friend:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/

For example, on the Button page:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Button.html

There is a Styles section that says what it uses. Show all the inherited ones to see the subclasses.

However, for complex items with sub-items, you have to look to see what they allow, too.